# Gravity using CircleShape SFML

Tags: c++, sfml, gravity

I am currently trying to set gravity for a split-screen game. The problem with my game is that the circles will rise once W or Up is pressed but the gravity does not seem to apply to them. Also when I move them left or right whilst in the air they disappear until I press W or Up again.

```
sf::Vector2f position(screenDimensions.x /2, screenDimensions.y / 2);
sf::Vector2f position2(position);

sf::Clock clock;

float moveSpeed = 0.5f , jumpSpeed = 0.3f;

   while(Game.isOpen())
{
    clock.restart();
    sf::Event Event;
    while(Game.pollEvent(Event))
    {
        switch(Event.type)
        {
        case sf::Event::Closed:
            Game.close();
            break;
        case sf::Event::KeyPressed:
            if(Event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Escape)
                Game.close();
            break;
        }
    }


if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Right))
        {
        velocity.x = moveSpeed;
        circ1.move(velocity.x, velocity.y);
        }
        else if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Left))
        {
            velocity.x = -moveSpeed;
            circ1.move(velocity.x, velocity.y);
        }
    else
        velocity.x = 0;

    if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::D))
        {
            velocity.x = moveSpeed;
            circ2.move(velocity.x, velocity.y);
        }
    else if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::A))
        {
            velocity.x = -moveSpeed;
            circ2.move(velocity.x, velocity.y);
        }
    else
        velocity.x = 0;

    if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Up))
        {
            velocity.y = -jumpSpeed;
            circ1.move(velocity.x, velocity.y);
        }
    else

    if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::W))
       {
           velocity.y = -jumpSpeed;
           circ2.move(velocity.x, velocity.y);
       }

    if (circ1.getPosition().x + 10 >= view1.getSize().x / 2)
        position.x = circ1.getPosition().x + 10;
    else
       position.x = view1.getSize().x / 2;

    if (circ2.getPosition().x + 10 >= view2.getSize().x / 2)
        position2.x = circ2.getPosition().x + 10;
    else
       position2.x = view2.getSize().x / 2;

    if (circ1.getPosition().y + circ1.getRadius() < groundHeight || velocity.y > 0)
        {
            velocity.y += Gravity;
        }
    else
        {
            circ1.setPosition(circ1.getPosition().x, groundHeight - circ1.getRadius());
            velocity.y = 0;
        }


    view1.setCenter(position);
    view2.setCenter(position2);

    Game.setView(view1);
    Game.draw(bImage);
    Game.draw(circ1);
    Game.draw(circ2);

    Game.setView(view2);
    Game.draw(bImage);
    Game.draw(circ2);
    Game.draw(circ1);
    Game.display();
    Game.clear();
}
```

}

Help is appreciated Thank you.

Comment: It would be great if we could have a look at the whole `while` loop

Comment: When asking a question on StackOverflow, you should **clean your code up of inessential parts** and **include only**, but all of **the necessary code**. For example - code, which is commented out is considered as inessential. So is the code for loading the image and designing the circles (in this case). On the other hand, what happens in `while` loop is necessary code and yet it is missing from your question.

Comment: I have changed the code, to the main parts. The while loop was shown further down that page. The while loop does not seem to be the problem, it is more to do with the gravity not working which does not involve the while loop at all.

Comment: `circ1.getPosition().y + circ1.getRadius() < groundHeight` so you only want to apply gravity when the circle is underground?

Comment: I changed circ1.getPosition().y + circ1.getRadius() < groundHeight to circ1.getPosition().y + circ1.getRadius() > groundHeight but now I can't get the circles to jump at all

Answer (score 0):

If you want "jumping" per se, then you need to keep the user from jumping while already in the air. This could be accomplished by creating a `bool jumping=false;` at the beginning and then setting `jumping`to true when a jump is initialized. Then, each time the program loops, `if (jumping && floor.getGlobalBounds().intersects(circ1) || circ.getPosition().y<0){jumping=false;velocity.y=0;}`.

Otherwise, you might try changing

```
 if (circ1.getPosition().y + circ1.getRadius() < groundHeight || velocity.y > 0)
        {
            velocity.y += Gravity;
        }
```

to

```
 if (circ1.getPosition().y + circ1.getRadius() > groundHeight || velocity.y > 0)
        {
            velocity.y += Gravity;
        }
```